# Cannot SSH to localhost - host key verification failed

Tags: ssh

I'm new to Linux. I have 2 Debian Squeeze hosts running. Let's call them *SqueezeOne* and *SqueezeTwo*. After logging into *SqueezeOne*, I ran `ssh-keygen` and added the resulting public key to my authorized key file:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I also added a public key generated by `puttygen` from my Windows desktop to the same key file.

I can `ssh` in from my putty just fine without being asked for my password. However, if I type in either of the following commands:

```
ssh localhost 
ssh One
```

I get the following error.

```
The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 75:56:33:22:c3:da:43:72:11:33:ec:50:f4:d0:dd:c7.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
Host key verification failed.
```

If I go to *SqueezeTwo*, and try to `ssh` to *SqueezeOne*, I receive the same message. On *SqueezeTwo*, there is a `~/.ssh/known_host` file, which I know did not create on my own. However, I am not seeing the same `known_hosts` file on *SqueezeOne*.

On *SqueezeTwo*, I can `ssh` to localhost and itself with no problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would expect the host key for localhost (127.0.0.1) to be different for each host.

Comment: obviously i'm a dumb a**. instead of typing yes, i hit enter, which defaults to no. when i type yes, an entry is automatically added to known_hosts. DUUUUUUUUUUUH!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 8):

Depending on what you are doing, it might be a good idea to not include localhost host key in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. This can be accomplished with the `NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost` option, either used on the command line with `-o NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost` or by inserting `NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost yes` into ~/.ssh/config.

Comment: That option is meant for people who have shared home directories across multiple servers.

Answer (score 2):

A hostkey identifies the machine.  The keys in your authorized_keys file identify you.  You should always expect to be prompted to accept the hostkey once for each machine you connect to.

If you are ever re-prompted for a machine you've already accepted, it may indicate something as innocuous as re-installing the SSH package, or as sinister as a man-in-the-middle attack.