# Cannot setup password less ssh on local host

Tags: ssh, openssh

I followed all the steps given in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439563/how-to-ssh-to-localhost-without-password/30169389#30169389) -

```
1. ssh-keygen -t rsa
Press enter for each line 
2. cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
3. chmod og-wx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I have also tried [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38444/cannot-ssh-to-localhost-host-key-verification-failed) -

```
This can be accomplished with the NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost option, either used on the command line with -o NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost or by inserting NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost yes into ~/.ssh/config.
```

All my permissions are correctly set i.e -

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user 1537 Feb 17 17:47 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user 1537 Feb 17 17:47 authorized_keys~
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  175 Oct 14 16:04 config
-rw-------. 1 user user 1743 Feb 17 17:44 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  399 Feb 17 17:44 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  739 Feb 17 17:41 id_rsa.pub~
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user 4803 Feb 10 10:52 known_hosts
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user 4397 Feb 10 10:52 known_hosts~
-rw-------. 1 user user 4803 Feb 10 10:31 known_hosts.old
```

permissions of .ssh -

```
drwx------.  2 user user    4096 Feb 17 17:47 .ssh
```

On doing a `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d`, following is the output -

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.3p1
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in use.
Cannot bind any address.
```

Output of ssh -v localhost

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/qubole/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/qubole/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/qubole/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/qubole/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/qubole/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/qubole/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/qubole/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/qubole/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/qubole/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Forcing accepting of host key for loopback/localhost.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_502' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_502' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_502' not found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/qubole/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/qubole/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/qubole/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/qubole/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Contents of ssh_config -

```
#   $OpenBSD: ssh_config,v 1.25 2009/02/17 01:28:32 djm Exp $

# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

# Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
Host *
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
# If this option is set to yes then remote X11 clients will have full access
# to the original X11 display. As virtually no X11 client supports the untrusted
# mode correctly we set this to yes.
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
# Send locale-related environment variables
    SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES 
    SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT 
    SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
    SendEnv XMODIFIERS
```

I still can't ssh to my localhost without a password. How do I set up a password less ssh to localhost?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: It's asking for password

Comment: What is showing ssh -v localhost ?

Comment: In sshd's config, what's the setting for `PubkeyAuthentication` ?

Comment: your authorized_keys file may be too readable - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6377073/4957508 - also - http://www.openssh.com/faq.html#3.14 -- unless you have StrictModes=no in sshd_config

Comment: Can you show us your sshd config file?

Comment: PubkeyAuthentication is commented out - #PubkeyAuthentication yes

Comment: Just to be sure. At this step "2. `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`" : are you adding it to the `authorized_keys` file on the remote machine, or your local one? Because it of course needs to be added on the remote machine.

Comment: I am trying to set up a password less ssh for local host, so I am adding it to the authorized_keys file on my local machine.

Comment: To ssh as A@local to A@local? If so also check `/var/log/auth.log` your ssh attempt will be logged there.

Comment: Also: you already meantioned `PubkeyAuthentication` to be commented out - what happens if you enable it and restart your ssh-server?

Comment: Still can't ssh. Error - Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). And there is no such file as auth.log

Comment: Check the `sshd` server log. It will tell you what is wrong with the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The `authorized keys` file's permissions should be no looser than 600 and the `.ssh` directory permissions should be 700. Anything more open than this, will give you trouble